# Conditional styling using `sx` in React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

Since `makeStyles` is deprecated: https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/. I'm trying to implement new approach with `sx` prop.

I'm having trouble understanding how to use it with React-Admin components.

Let's say I have a list of Logs which can be `Error`, `Warning`, or `Info` under `type` field, and I want to color it appropriately.

I've tried something like this:

```js
const LogList = ({ permissions, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <List
      {...props}
      title="Logs"
      filters={<LogFilter />}
      perPage={25}
      bulkActionButtons={false}
    >
      <Datagrid rowClick="show">
        <TextField
          source="type"
          label="Type"
          sx={ record.type === "Error" ? {color: "red"} : {color: "blue"}}
        />
        <TextField
          source="description"
          label="Description"
        />
        <DateField
          source="createdAt"
          label="Created At"
        />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

But `record` cannot be used in `sx`.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the record, for example with the `useRecordContext()` hook:

```
import { useRecordContext, TextField } from 'react-admin'
...
const TypeField = () => {
  const record = useRecordContext()

  return (
    <TextField
      source="type"
      label="Type"
      sx={{ color: record?.type === "Error" ? "red" : "blue" }}
    />
  )    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sx={{color:record.type === "Error" ? "red":"blue"}}
```

Try this one

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Gives the error: `record is not defined`.